# How SharePoint works with Infopath and an Access database?

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath, form, database, microsoft-access

I have a database already created in Access. It has a form which uses queries with macros to export an excel with the information chosen from the form. 
SharePoint would be the perfect tool to share that form with other coworkers. Therefore they can fill up the form and only obtain in an excel the information required, without seeing the background of the data.

Is it possible to have a form in SharePoint (using infopath or other tool you recommend) that:
        1) Connects with the database on the server, and export an excel with the data required in the mentioned form
        2) Without having to upload the whole database to SharePoint, because I'm only want them to see what they export in a n excel, not the whole database.

To sum up, how can I create that link between SharePoint and Access, without uploading the database to SharePoint?

The events will be:
       1) A coworker access to SharePoint to fill up the form specifying what information he/she wants to have
       2) Click a button that Runs the macros and queries to compute the desired data in the database
       3) A macro from the database exports an excel with the desired information
       4) That excel could be added to the SharePoint, so the coworker can download it

I hope is as detailed and easy to understand as I think.